# Use one fragment many times in viewpager

Tags: android

I'm trying to use one fragment in a viewpager multiple times, I am trying to build a dynamically updated UI using ViewPager. I want to use the same design, basically the same fragment with different data for every page but I don't know how to do this. Any suggestion ?
This is may Adapter, FragmentActivity and fragment

```
public MonPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment>fragments)
{
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return this.fragments.size();
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) 
{
    //CalendrierMens cm = new CalendrierMens();
    CalendrierMens cm = new CalendrierMens();
    cm.date_actuelle.set(cm.date_actuelle.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1);
    cm.updateTable(cm.date_actuelle.get(Calendar.YEAR), cm.date_actuelle.get(Calendar.MONTH), cm.date_actuelle.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    ((ViewPager)pager).addView(CalendrierMens.newInstance().getView());
    return super.instantiateItem(pager, position);
}
```

---

```
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mois_annee = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mois_annee);
    mois_annee.setText(getMonthForInt(date_actuelle.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"  "+date_actuelle.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    this.creerGrille();
    this.updateTable(date_actuelle.get(Calendar.YEAR), date_actuelle.get(Calendar.MONTH), date_actuelle.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
public static CalendrierMens newInstance()
{
    CalendrierMens fragment = new CalendrierMens();
    //Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //args.put
    //fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

---

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);

```
    // Création de la liste des Fragments que fera défiler le PagerAdapter
    List<Fragment>fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    // Ajout des Fragments dans la liste
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,CalendrierMens.class.getName()));
    //fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageMilieuFragment.class.getName()));
    //fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageDroiteFragment.class.getName()));

    // Création de l'adapter qui s'occupera de l'affichage de la liste des Fragments
    this.monPagerAdapter = new MonPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    // Affectation de l'adapter au ViewPager
    pager.setAdapter(this.monPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: I create a fragment that contains the code of my monthly calendar, a fragmentActivity that managing my Viewpageradapter, and an adapter that inherits FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: this is the code of my adapter:public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) 
 {
  //CalendrierMens cm = new CalendrierMens();
  CalendrierMens cm = new CalendrierMens();
  cm.date_actuelle.set(cm.date_actuelle.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1);
  cm.updateTable(cm.date_actuelle.get(Calendar.YEAR), cm.date_actuelle.get(Calendar.MONTH), cm.date_actuelle.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  ((ViewPager)pager).addView(CalendrierMens.newInstance().getView());
  return super.instantiateItem(pager, position);
 }

Comment: edit your question and post relevant snipped of code

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = "";   
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

         CalendrierMens cm = new CalendrierMens();
         Bundle bundle = new Budle();
         switch(arg0) {
         case 0:
          // set args for case 0
           break;
         }
        cm.setArguments(bundle);
        return cm;
    }


}
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not change anything, I want when I slide to the right or left the current month changes, maybe I have a problem with the code that changing the date

Comment: Is that the instantiateItem a mandatory method ? Is that the content is correct? and is what I did not need to implement listener ?

Comment: if you extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter it is not